# Trouble calling js functions with prepack.io

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-watch, prepack

I have this function in a js file (not really spectacular):

```
function loadLazyImages() {
    var lazyImages = document.querySelectorAll('.js-lazyload');
}
loadLazyImages();
```

I also have a gulp task that concatenates and uglifies this file among others. This worked fine in the past, but now I'm trying out '[prepack](https://prepack.io/repl.html)' and there seems to be a problem:

```
not an object
TypeError
    at loadLazyImages (unknown:12:22)
    at unknown:15:1
C:\...\node_modules\prepack\lib\prepack-standalone.js:59
    throw new InitializationError();
```

The documentation states something about `document` and `window` not being defined but is rather vague when it comes tot solutions. Any insights?

Comment: I don't know much about prepack but it seems that from reading their issue tracker on GitHub you just can't do this yet (e.g. [see this issue](https://github.com/facebook/prepack/issues/24)).

Answer (score 0):

Try run prepack with `--trace` option.